# Push Notifications : FCM : Https Issue

Tags: https, push, notifications

As per the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client,

> The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due
>   to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS
>   sites. Need a provider? Firebase Hosting is an easy way to get free
>   HTTPS hosting on your own domain.

During development, I need to test push notifications on our QA environment which is on private network.

For this, we created a self-signed certificate. however, chrome shows that the certificate is invalid.

How can I test push notifications for an internal server when I cannot get a certificate for it, since it is part of internal network of the organizatin?

Comment: Assuming your local QA environment for which the self-signed certificate has been issued is not your localhost then the previous answer won't work. I'm going to post a couple different answers, one of these may work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that browsers won't reject communication with the QA server, you can take the self-signed certificate and install it on all hosts that need to access the local QA environment by following the instructions [here](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Install_a_trusted_root_CA__or_self-signed_certificate)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the solution for access via `http://localhost` works, you could set up a webserver (an instance of apache or nginx) on each host that needs to access the QA environment, set up to:

- only accept connections from localhost (for security)
- reverse proxy all connections to the QA environment - including any extra configuration to support particular features you require, e.g. websockets

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the self-signed certificate, just go to localhost using unencrypted HTTP. I never used FCM's JS SDK, but service workers indeed only work on HTTPS *and* on `http://localhost`. I suspect the same rule therefore applies to FCM.